# Changing the style of index levels

Tags: formatting, indexing, imakeidx

I would like to change the style of the levels in an index. For example, let's say I have an index like:

```
Foo
    bar, 1
    barbar, 2
Bar
    foo, 5
```

and I would like the first level to be emphasized ("Foo" and "Bar"). I'm already using `imakeidx` for this document. How could I achive this?

Comment: You may use the key `othercode` in `\indexsetup` to change the definition of `\item`, but it's necessary to know how the `.ind` file is structured.

Comment: @egreg: do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output of makeindex is something like

```
\item \BRbooktitlestyle {\BRbookof Daniel}
```

it should be sufficient to say

```
\renewcommand*{\BRbooktitlestyle}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

in your preamble

Comment: In the preamble in the `.ist` right?

Comment: I'm actually using it just before calling `\printindex` and it works fine.

Comment: That works for books. At first level, I have "Old Testament" and "New Testament" entries, defined implicitely because I use things like `\biblerefmap{Gn}{1@Ancien Testament!01}`. Is there a way I can also change the style for these implicit entries?

Comment: @Raphink Without a minimal example it's really impossible to help. The redefinition of `\BRbooktitlestyle` should go in the document's preamble, but before `\printindex` is good as well.