# Change top level grouping of an index

Tags: indexing, xindy, imakeidx

In the "Name Index" there are only a *few* possible categories: "animal", "artists", "mineral" and "plant", in this example.

For just this "Name Index", how do I eliminate the "A", "M" and "P" letter categories -- especially in the bookmarks? I don't want this to alter the other indices.

[image]

I would prefer the bookmarks looked like:

```
Name Index
    Animal
    Artists
    Mineral
    Plant

Main Index
    C
    D
    T
```

### Related Question

- [Changing the style of index levels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/changing-the-style-of-index-levels) seems related.

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{\subsection{#1}}

\newcommand*{\IndexWithName}[2]{%
    % #1 = word to index
    % #2 = index name
    \index[#2]{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatIndexEntry}{mm}{%
    \textcolor{blue}{#1} #2%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddIndexEntry}{%
    O{}% #1 = index name
      m% #2 = word to index this under
      m% #3 = indexed term
      m% #4 = symbol (not used in this MWE)
}{%
    \expandafter\IndexWithName\expandafter{%
        #2!#3@\FormatIndexEntry{#3}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#4}}}%
    }{#1}%
}

\makeindex[title={Main Index},columns=1,program=texindy,name=Main]
\makeindex[title={Name Index},columns=1,program=texindy,name=Name]
\indexsetup{level=\section}

\begin{document}
some text

\AddIndexEntry[Main]{tree}{leaf}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Main]{tree}{trunk}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Main]{dog}{labrador retriever}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Main]{dog}{german shpherd}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Main]{cat}{siamese}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Main]{cat}{persian}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Main]{cat}{bengal}{}

\AddIndexEntry[Name]{artists}{Picasso}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{artists}{van Gogh}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{artists}{da Vinci}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{plant}{tree}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{plant}{shrub}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{animal}{fox}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{animal}{cat}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{mineral}{quartz}{}
\AddIndexEntry[Name]{mineral}{marble}{}

\clearpage 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\printindex[Name]
\printindex[Main]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have to attack this problem from the `xindy` part of the 'problem'. In one case you want to have the `lettergroup` as a bookmark entry, in the other one, it's the `\item animal` etc. entry. Lettergroup is easy (as you have shown), but `\item ...` ... :-(